# Algorithm that generates a n-simplex that cover n-polytope?

Tags: co.combinatorics, computer-science, computational-geometry

Given an $n$-cube with unit volume, is there any algorithm that generates a $n$-simplex that covers the $n$-polytope?

Answer (score 5):

There is a nontrivial algorithm in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the minimum volume tetrahedron
circumscribing an arbitrary polyhedron (i.e., not specifically a cube):

> Zhou, Yunhong, and Subhash Suri. "Algorithms for a minimum volume enclosing simplex in three dimensions." *SIAM Journal on Computing* 31.5 (2002): 1339-1357.
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=338599).)
>   
>                  
>   [image: SuriFig6]

This work relies on a beautiful theorem of Victor Klee, valid in all dimensions,
that implies touching at facet centroids (as one can see in the above figure):

> V. Klee, Facet-centroids and volume minimization, *Studia Sci.Math.Hungar.*, 21 (1986),
>   pp.143–147.